# jquery, add variable to element?

Tags: jquery, variables, element

I have a question regarding jQuery. I have a `li` that slides out, now I want to remember if it has slided out so I want to set a boolean variable `slidedOut`.

Is it possible to simply add it to the element? Or should I add a hidden `div` or something to to element?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [**`.data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) for this.

Something like

```
$("#yourli").data("slidedOut", false);
```

Comment: you can get the value using `var value = $("#yourli").data("slidedOut");`

Answer (score 1):

Using [jquery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is considered the standard way to do it - although there are tons of other ways to do it.

An alternative is simply:

```
 $("#myli")[0].slidedOut = true;
 alert($("#myli")[0].slidedOut);
```

Comment: Your example won't work. You create a new object every time you call `$()`, so setting a property one one will not affect any others, even when it's the same element selected. Note that `$('#myli')[0].slidedOut` *would* work, but it's hardly best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use CSS classes. This is particularity useful if you don't really save data (just a flag), or want to change the design for these `<li>`s or their children.

- [`.addClass('visited')`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) - Add the class when needed.
- [`.hasClass('visited')`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) - Checks if the element has this class.
- `removeClass('visited')`